# How can I retain same state in landscape mode in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I retain same state in landscape.
 when I rotted the screen in landscape mode then activity is restarted and 
my layout view is showing wrong. so please help me.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "view is showing wrong" can you attach screenshots with right and wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may save your state in a `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()` method and restore it back in `onCreate()` or in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

or if you want to disable orientation changes, you may add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to your `Activity` in the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you sir.
can you tell me how can I save layout view in onSavedInstanceState().

Comment: Thanks You Sir,
But when I change the rotation mode then activity is restarted. And I'm using random function. So I can't retain same color of activity on landscape mode. that's a problem.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh well, don't user random. save all important variables and states into the `Bundle` to be restored later. Or disable rotations at all (see the second part of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

For  retain same state in landscape mode you must add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"`  in your Current Activity to Handle Configuration Change in your on way as:

```
<activity
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
 ...
 />
```

or for Changing Layout or any View on `configChanges` you must override `onConfigurationChanged` of Activity as:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    //Handle config changes here, paying attention to
    //the newConfig.orientation value
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and if you want to save state on any view on Configuration Chnages then you must override `onSaveInstanceState()` for saving state of view like TextView, EditText,View Layout's .. and  `onRestoreInstanceState()` for Retrieving state back after Device mode rotation.

for more info about how we handle runtime changes you can also see this android topic :

[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Thanks You Sir,
But when I change the rotation mode then activity is restarted. And I'm using random function. So I can't retain same color of activity on landscape mode. that's a problem.

Comment: then use `onSaveInstanceState()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()` method for saving or retrieving background colors for activity on landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

If your speaking that your layout doesnt look/fit properly in landscape mode then you will need a new xml with the same name & place it inside a new folder called "layout-land". That should help

Comment: Thanks You Sir,
But when I change the rotation mode then activity is restarted. And I'm using random function. So I can't retain same color of activity on landscape mode. that's a problem.

Comment: How are you setting those colors?  u generate a random number & based on the umber you set the color right?  Why not save the number generated in a variable & then use it in saveInstanceState() !